# Is it possible to prove that ceil(x/y) = ceil(ceil(x)/ceil(y))?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\operatorname{ceil}(x)$ be the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. (Also denoted $\lceil x\rceil$.)

Is it true that $\operatorname{ceil}(x/y) = \operatorname{ceil}(\operatorname{ceil}(x)/\operatorname{ceil}(y))$?

It would help me out if this would be provable but I am not that familiar with the ceil and floor functions in mathematics. I am not sure what properties I could apply.

Comment: Hint: Try some small examples.  Become familiar with the ceiling function, it is not that difficult.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is not true.

Consider $x=0.9$ and $y=0.1$ then $\lceil\frac{x}{y}\rceil=9$ while $\lceil\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{\lceil y\rceil}\rceil=1$

Comment: Would it be true if y were an element of Z?

Comment: @LiamMartens. Yes. Graph $\lceil\frac{x}{2}\rceil$ and $\lceil\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{2}\rceil$ to get an intuition.

Comment: @RickDecker and how would one prove this?

Comment: @LiamMartens If $\lceil \frac x2 \rceil=n$, then $n-1<\frac x2 \leq n$. So, $2n-2<x\leq 2n$. Thus, $2n-2 < \lceil x \rceil \leq 2n$. So, $n-1<\frac{\lceil x \rceil}{2} \leq n$. Therefore, $\left\lceil \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{2} \right\rceil =n$. You can generalize this for other integers than 2.